# explain HTTP headers x-ca-image-adapte-size x-ca-image-original-size

Tags: image, http, web, hosting, photoshop

can sumbody explain these http headers?

x-ca-image-adapte-size:608,208, 
x-ca-image-original-size:676,232

I got them with http://hotelmarketonline.com/websites/designcare_com/img/logo.png this image that I have hosted with godaddy.

This image is in a good quality when checked from filezilla. but when it is viewed in the browser it looks really poor. I think the problem is related with these headers.

Comment: Do you see this header also for other images served from other webservers? Are you online using your mobile phone?

Comment: I got these for some other images as well and they also were poor in quality. anyway now i am not getting those headers and image looks fine. reason is unknown. (not from a mobile phone)

Answer (score 1):

These are no official HTTP headers (indicated by the prefix `X-`), thus, they are not evaluated by (most) browsers. - A list of official and wide-spread HTTP headers can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

back to your problem:
I don't get these headers when I request the file with my browser.

I suppose GoDaddy (or your ISP) has some plugin/module in their webserver or between you and the webserver adjusting images and inserting this header.

E.g. sometimes ISPs of mobile links compress images on the fly in order to speed up the delivery and page loading.

Comment: something has happened and i also don't get these headers and now the image looks ok